# i ran into this strange error: TypeError: invalid destination position for blit

Tags: python, pygame

i want to display the number of bullets i have left on the screen  but after writing the screen.blit function and with the proper parameters, i got that strange error. please help out. i can't seem how to resolve the error.
this is the draw_text function

```
def draw_text(text, font, text_col, x, y):
    img = font.render(text, True, text_col)
    screen.blit(img, (x, y))
```

bullet class

```
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, direction):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.speed = 10
        self.image = bullet_img
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (x, y)
        self.direction = direction
```

then the main game loop

```
while run:
    clock.tick(fps)
    draw_bg()
    # show ammo
    draw_text("AMMO:", font, WHITE, 10, 35)
    for x in range(player.ammo):
        screen.blit(bullet_img, (90 + (x * 10)), 40)
    # show grenade
```

the full error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\FSTC\Downloads\spaceproject\main.py", line 323, in <module>
    screen.blit(bullet_img, (90 + (x * 10)), 40)
TypeError: invalid destination position for blit
```

is this as a result of a typo or something else? please help out.

Comment: Please show the error and full stack trace.

Comment: @wkl: this is the error gotten.. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\FSTC\Downloads\spaceproject\main.py", line 323, in <module>
    screen.blit(bullet_img, (90 + (x * 10)), 40)
TypeError: invalid destination position for blit

Comment: Compare `draw_text` with how you called `screen.blit` in your main loop. (Hint: the argument counts are different.)

Comment: Might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73293157/i-ran-into-this-strange-error-typeerror-invalid-destination-position-for-blit

Answer (score 0):

The parenthesis are wrong

<s>`screen.blit(bullet_img, (90 + (x * 10)), 40)`</s>

```py
screen.blit(bullet_img, (90 + (x * 10), 40))
```